# Algorithm for detecting closed region on a plane

Tags: ds.algorithms, cg.comp-geom

First off, I just want to say that I am not well versed in computational geometry, so if this question has some obvious answer, I apologize.  I tried googling it but I could not find anything.

My question: Given an input of a plane with 1 or more line segments, is there an efficient algorithm for determining if there exists a closed region on this plane?  For example, see the following picture:

benjamindicken.com/closed_region.png

On this plane, there exists one closed region.  I would like the algorithm to return true if a closed region exists, and false if one does not.

At the moment, I only need this algorithm to determine if a closed region exists or not, but I could foresee needing this to return the number of closed regions as well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the input to your problem ? A collection of lines ?

Comment: Also, if you have three lines that aren't parallel or concurrent, there will always be one closed region.

Comment: Yes, the input would be a collection of lines.  However, I am trying to apply this to edges on a graph (treating each line edge as a line on a plane).  Thus, they are really a collection of line SEGMENTS, not full lines.  Sorry, I should have made that more clear.

Comment: By default, graphs don't have coordinates, and their edges are formally pairs of vertices, not line segments.  What is your input _really_?

Comment: Yes, I know this.  This algorithm will be applied not to graphs, but to a graph drawing/layout in order to test for various properties.  I am laying out the edges of the graph at particular (x,y) coordinates on a plane, and then representing each edge as a straight line segment between the two points.  I do this for all edges.  After doing this, I remove certain segments (or parts of segments) a little at a time.  At various intervals, I would like to check if the graph contains a closed region on a plane.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be a set of segments with the property that no two segments have an intersection with positive length. The set $S$ bounds a region if and only if the intersection graph of the segments in $S$ has a cycle.

Comment: Yes.  However After drawing the graph edges on a plane, I will be removing some of the line segments (and segments of the segments).  That is why I didn't initially ask the question in terms on graph drawing, because after drawing the graph edges as segments, I will be altering the segments length, or removing them altogether. Thus "A set of straight-line segments bounds a region if and only if the intersection graph of the segments has a cycle" may not still hold after alteration.

Comment: Also, your statement is not necessarily true... it all depends on how the graph is drawn.

Comment: For example, one could have the set of segments $\: \left\{\left[\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle\right],\left[\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 2,0\rangle\right],\left[\langle 1,0\rangle,\langle 2,0\rangle\right]\right\} \:$. $\;\;$

Comment: I was assuming that segments do not overlap, which perhaps may be assuming too much. I will edit it to make it clear.

Comment: @bddicken: if the segments change, the intersection graph also changes.

Comment: @bddicken: I think you need to know what is an intersection graph.  An intersection graph is combinatorial, so the existence of a cycle doesn't depend on how it's drawn. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_graph